# Automatic expand userform checkbox when sheet is added

Tags: excel, checkbox, userform, vba

I need a userform with a checkbox to run some routine. This userform needs checkboxes to be expand based on the number of sheets. So with one sheet there must be only one checkbox with two, two checkboxes etc. The number of sheet are various and based on user input by a ribbon button.
Can some help me a bit on the road to get this going.
Below the code I allready have. I think ther must be a much nicer way to do this.

```
Private Sub All_Sheets_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
 x = 1
 For i = 1 To 30
 With Userform1
 .Controls("SheetCheckBox" & x).value = True
 End With
 x = x + 1
 Next i
End Sub
Private Sub Undo_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
 x = 1
 For i = 1 To 30
 With Userform1
 .Controls("SheetCheckBox" & x).value = False
 End With
 x = x + 1
 Next i
End Sub
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim numsht As Long
    numsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    If numsht = 1 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 2 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 3 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 4 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 5 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 6 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 7 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 8 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 9 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 10 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 11 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 12 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 13 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 14 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 15 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 16 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 17 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 18 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 19 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 20 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 21 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 22 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 23 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 24 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox24.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 25 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox24.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox25.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 26 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox24.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox25.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox26.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 27 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox24.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox25.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox26.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox27.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 28 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox24.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox25.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox26.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox27.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox28.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 29 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox24.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox25.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox26.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox27.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox28.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox29.Visible = True
        ElseIf numsht = 30 Then
            SheetCheckBox1.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox2.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox3.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox4.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox5.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox6.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox7.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox8.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox9.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox10.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox11.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox12.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox13.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox14.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox15.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox16.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox17.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox18.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox19.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox20.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox21.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox22.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox23.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox24.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox25.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox26.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox27.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox28.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox29.Visible = True
            SheetCheckBox30.Visible = True
        Else:
            MsgBox "Need more checkboxes!" & vbNewLine & "Contact Jan Wieland for more details", vbCritical
    End If
    'Uncheck DataCheckBoxes
    SheetCheckBox1.value = False
    SheetCheckBox2.value = False
    SheetCheckBox3.value = False
    SheetCheckBox4.value = False
    SheetCheckBox5.value = False
    SheetCheckBox6.value = False
    SheetCheckBox7.value = False
    SheetCheckBox8.value = False
    SheetCheckBox9.value = False
    SheetCheckBox10.value = False
    SheetCheckBox11.value = False
    SheetCheckBox12.value = False
    SheetCheckBox13.value = False
    SheetCheckBox14.value = False
    SheetCheckBox15.value = False
    SheetCheckBox16.value = False
    SheetCheckBox17.value = False
    SheetCheckBox18.value = False
    SheetCheckBox19.value = False
    SheetCheckBox20.value = False
    SheetCheckBox21.value = False
    SheetCheckBox22.value = False
    SheetCheckBox23.value = False
    SheetCheckBox24.value = False
    SheetCheckBox25.value = False
    SheetCheckBox26.value = False
    SheetCheckBox27.value = False
    SheetCheckBox28.value = False
    SheetCheckBox29.value = False
    SheetCheckBox30.value = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Hi DragonSamu. I'm aware that SO is not for code writing service. But I have read a lot of codes to try but until now not one was usefull. I'm not a frequuent user of VBA and got a running project to improve. So it's not common sense to me :)

Comment: I understand, but you still need to show your effort. Currently your question stands as asking for code but not showing any effort or research done. SO is a site meant for everyone once your question is answered other people might learn from it. Currently no one will learn from this as its pure code request. Edit the question and provide your research and what you tried, then you'll see people will be more then willing to help.

Comment: Hi DragonSamu,You may close this topic as with StanB's suggestion I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I made a very simple userform with 5 checkboxes.

I then hid each checkbox in the properties window:

[image: Visible.False]

Then I put this code in the code section of the userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim numsht As Long
numsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
If numsht = 1 Then
        CheckBox1.Visible = True
    ElseIf numsht = 2 Then
        CheckBox1.Visible = True
        CheckBox2.Visible = True
    ElseIf numsht = 3 Then
        CheckBox1.Visible = True
        CheckBox2.Visible = True
        CheckBox3.Visible = True
    ElseIf numsht = 4 Then
        CheckBox1.Visible = True
        CheckBox2.Visible = True
        CheckBox3.Visible = True
        CheckBox4.Visible = True
    ElseIf numsht = 5 Then
        CheckBox1.Visible = True
        CheckBox2.Visible = True
        CheckBox3.Visible = True
        CheckBox4.Visible = True
        CheckBox5.Visible = True
    Else:
        MsgBox "Need more checkboxes!" & vbNewLine & "Contact Jan Wieland for more details", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Experiment with different amount of sheets...

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks StanB. I will give this a try. The problem however is that the sheet is being used randomly. At the moment a project has 28 items(sheets). So is there a way to expand the number of checkboxes dynamicly? This will keep the code as clean as possible.

Comment: @JanWieland, you would use `.add` method, see [this page](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson21.htm)

Comment: @jan feel free to mark it as 'answered' ;)

Comment: I would if I know how :)